# How to create recovery media for Windows 10 (UEFI)?

Tags: windows-10, data-recovery

From my research, using the "Reset" option in Windows 10's advanced settings no longer does a complete reset, keeping already installed updates or something like that.

So, how can I create a true recovery disk that will be able to restore the computer even if Windows isn't on there to begin with?

I want, essentially, the end result to be the same as older computers which shipped with OEM recovery media.

Edit: This is a **UEFI** machine.

Comment: Have you seen [Microsoft's Windows download page](https://www.microsoft.com/software-download/windows10)?

Comment: @gronostaj Yes, but that will give me a Win10 ISO (without HW-specific drivers). I want media that will restore a blank hard drive to the state in which the machine first was when I bought it.

Comment: @gronostaj Also, the manufacturer doesn't provide drivers on their website.

Comment: @MarkYisri There isn't a feature that does what you want

Comment: The Reset windows allows you to choose what you want to do. There is a factory reset option too which will restore to the first moment after installation, removing all files, drivers, etc. Alternatively, you can download the Media Creation Tool, which you can use to create a USB stick. You can install windows from that USB stick and choose to delete all partitions like an old fashioned install.

Comment: @LPChip I thought that W10 removed the need for a recovery partition, thus it's not a complete restore.

Comment: @MarkYisri After installing windows, a restore point is made. Reset is resetting it to that point, removing all files and folders after that point. Isn't that what you're after?

Comment: @LPChip I didn't install W10, it's preinstalled by the manufacturer.

Comment: @MarkYisri if you haven't performed a clean install of windows on the machine before, then indeed using reset won't work, and you need to create a bootable USB disk.

Comment: @LPChip okay, does that mean that I create installation media? Because that won't give me the custom drivers from the MF.

Comment: Windows includes many drivers by default using windows update. But in worst case, downloading the network card drivers and add them to the stick so you can download the necessary drivers later is always an option. I rarely download drivers nowadays anymore. Windows 10 supports almost everything.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer depends on Windows 10 being it's "factory fresh" self, and first login being done. I wouldn't recommend doing this on a machine that's already been in use for any significant amount of time and hasn't just been wiped.**

In the case of a new/freshly wiped machine, it would be a good idea to have something like Clonezilla/[some other cloning software] make a copy of the drive and keep that on a USB stick.

Most cloning utilities can be made to ignore free space, so something like a 32gb USB stick should cover full uncompressed Windows install.

That way, if something goes wrong, you already have a good copy of Windows with all the drivers preinstalled and the account already created.

If you do this before installing anything, you'll have a stable, virus-free, guaranteed working copy of your machine ready to go if something goes wrong(HDD/SSD failure, ransomware/virus, [screwing up your partition when playing with disk utilities like DiskPart], ...).

You end up copying the stick back onto the new(in case of a failure) drive, then expand the free space/make a new partition from the rest, depending on preference.

Side note:

If you have 2 512MB-1GB USB sticks sitting in a drawer, you could put Clonezilla on one, GParted on the other. Stick all 3 sticks in a baggie and that baggie now contains all of the tools you need to restore your system from nothing. (Some learning may be required, but Clonezilla/GParted aren't that hard to learn and are financially and legally free.)

Add a USB stick with the pictures/movies/documents you can't afford to lose on it, and throw that in the baggie, then throw the baggie into one of those small fireproof safes and have another family member/friend/other person you trust take the safe home, and you also have a backup that's offsite(in case of Act of God).

Hmmm....I need to go follow my own advice now...

Comment: I have used GParted multiple times before, and learning Clonezilla shouldn't take long. But this will be an exact copy of my disk, not a recovery image.

Comment: True. That's why I mentioned doing this on a "new/freshly wiped" machine.  The machine would need to be in that state for stability to be roughly guaranteed, but that doesn't mean you can't do it after taking good backups of your existing data.

Answer (score -1):

Steps here:

- Buy USB 2.0 thumb drive / stick / whatever. 4GB is enough (for 7 it definitely is, for 10 I think so but maybe double check this) but a little bigger doesn't hurt anything. I usually load copies of my hardware drivers and some other useful utilities onto a separate, smaller partition (on that same USB drive) to streamline my installations.
- Download a Win10 image directly from MS.
- Use DiskPart to format the drive, accessing it by running cmd.exe as an administrator. Be careful and use a guide if you need to, DiskPart is not an application that you should be using willy nilly. It is entirely possible to select the wrong drive and erase your primary storage drive or any others connected, so be sure that you have your disk numbers correct before you input commands. Disk Manager can be a helpful utility if you're having trouble visualizing which drives are which and what their labels are. You can also take this time to name your drive, assign it a specific drive letter, and do a few other things to give it unique identifiers.
- Mini Diskpart guide: clean the USB drive (this will erase everything on it, back up any existing data); create a primary partition (and a secondary if you wish) making sure it is large enough to fit the Windows install media; format the partition in NTFS; mark it as active; exit diskpart and cmd by typing "exit" twice with no quotes. There are plenty of guides that go into more detail about each of these steps. Here's a resource I use a lot when I work on this kind of stuff: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766465(v=ws.10).aspx
- Using a program like DaemonTools Lite or your open source equivalent, create a virtual disk drive and mount that Win10 disk image. DaemonTools makes this process incredibly easy and they have a free version of their software for anyone to use.
- Open file explorer and view the contents of the Win10 disk image. You'll see a bunch of folders and stuff in there. Copy all of those items to your USB thumb drive.
- Open Disk Manager in Windows and look at the USB thumb drive to verify that you have an NTFS formatted partition which is marked active and is loaded with the appropriate amount of data for what you just copied onto it.
- Test your new bootable drive by restarting, entering BIOS, and setting up the requisite boot configuration to boot from your USB drive. Exit BIOS, and you should boot directly into the Windows Recovery Media. From there you should be able to detect repair any existing Windows installations and install a fresh copy of Windows regardless of whether or not other installations exist.

This is how you accomplish what you're asking without using the Media Creation Tool and whatever other nonsense. Don't trust someone to do it for you; build it yourself, admin it yourself, it's the only way to know for sure that it was done correctly. Following these steps will create exactly what you want, specifically this part:

> So, how can I create a true recovery disk that will be able to restore the computer even if Windows isn't on there to begin with?
>
> I want, essentially, the end result to be the same as older computers which shipped with OEM recovery media.

Yeap this is how you make one of these.

EDIT: Comma stuff

Comment: Its bad practice to write an answer if you're not sure, let alone saying that you are not sure. At least 3 GB is required if you make an installation media for just one OS version that is only x64 or x86. 6GB is required if you make a version for one OS that is both x64 and x86.

Comment: @LPChip I only need one version, but it is a long answer and I can figure out how to do it on my own as I have experience with partitioning/EFI.

Comment: @MarkYisri do note, this is not my answer.

Comment: @LPChip I'm new to the community I will keep this in mind, thank you. Would it ahve been better practice to write out the actual diskpart commands as well instead of recommending a guide?

Comment: @jcam3 yes, because links can become invalid and then your answer becomes invalid too. :) Anyway, welcome aboard. :)